# dotnet interactive jupyter install command not found

Tags: .net-core, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Trying to follow the install instructions from here: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNETInteractiveTryNETIncludesNETNotebooksAndMore.aspx

I get to the step where it tries to tell jupyter cli that .net interactive exists: 
   `dotnet interactive jupyter install`
I get a response: `Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.` from the Anaconda prompt.

`jupyter kernelspec list` shows that phyton3 is available, and I can launch notebooks using 'jupyter notebook'

Not sure what do to next to resolve? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I fully restarted my Anaconda Navigator